# Botão de modal some quando uso o scroll do navegador

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, modal

Queria deixar o botão do modal fixo no topo da página, porém quando uso o *scroll* do navegador, o botão de fechar some, isso só acontece em um dos modais sendo que todos os 7 são exatamente iguais.

```
<div id="bg-egipcia" class="bg font-shadow">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="glyphicon-modal glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-egito"></span>
            <p class="text-shadow-titulo bold egito">"...</p>
            <p class="text-shadow-titulo bold egito">...</p>
            <p class="text-shadow-titulo bold egito">...</p>
            <p class="text-shadow-titulo bold egito">.....</p>
            <p class="text-shadow-titulo egito" id="egito">.....</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade padding-modal-curiosidadaes" id="modal-egito" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div id="bg-sala-egipcia-modal" class="bg-modal modal-content">
            <div class="modal-content no-border-radius">
                <button class="close texte">
                    <span class="btn-egito ajuste-btn-curiosidades" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-body no-padding">
                    <div class="div-texto div-texto-egito col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
                        <p><strong class="strong-curiosidades">HISTÓRICO</strong><br></p>
                        <p>texto qualquer  texto qualquer texto qualquer  texto qualquer  <br><br></p>

                        <p><strong class="strong-curiosidades">MÍSTICA</strong><br></p>
                        <p>texto qualquer  texto qualquer texto qualquer  texto qualquer  <br><br></p>

                        <p><strong class="strong-curiosidades">PERFEIÇÃO</strong><br></p>
                        <p>texto qualquer  texto qualquer texto qualquer  texto qualquer  </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <img src="img/bg-curiosidades/img-hieroglifos.jpg" alt="hieróglifos">
                    </div>
                    <div class="div-texto div-texto-egito col-xs-12  col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                        <p><strong class="strong-curiosidades">HIERÓGLIFOS</strong><br></p>
                        <p>texto qualquer  texto qualquer texto qualquer  texto qualquer  </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div-texto div-texto-egito col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <img class="ajuste-img-egito" src="img/bg-curiosidades/img-egito.jpg" alt="img-egito">
                        <p><strong class="strong-curiosidades">IMORTALIDADE</strong><br></p>
                        <p>texto qualquer  texto qualquer texto qualquer  texto qualquer  </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Não consegui rodar o seu HTML, mesmo com Boostrap, poderia postar no Fiddle o código executável para verificar se posso te ajudar?

Comment: Tente ver o código no fiddle por esse link 

https://jsfiddle.net/2d9uxyma/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=2d9uxyma

Answer (score -1, accepted):

consegui resolver.

coloquei uma tag "a" que seta o href para o topo da página.

Comment: Oi Lucas, que bacana que você resolveu o seu problema. Poderia colocar o snippet de código com a tag `a` utilizada para outras pessoas que enfrentem o mesmo tipo de problema?

Comment: <a id="qualquer_id" href="qualquer_id">Teste Modal</a>

Comment: esse é o a que abre o modal